# Convert Object Array Element in JSON

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

Maybe a stupid question, but I can't do this. So:

I have something like this:

```
obj = {to:this.to,all:[]};
```

`all:[{},{},{},...]` but this is not important

If I do `JSON.stringify(obj.all)` it returns only this `[]` without `all` .

How to achive this `{ all: [] }` ?

Comment: `JSON.stringify({ all: obj.all })`?

Comment: Is not a way to use Object to assign this {} ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this -

```
let obj = {to:this.to,all:[]};
let objNew = Object.assign({}, {all: obj.all});
```

Comment: Yes something like this, but the 2nd parameter something like obj.all

Comment: Ok this is the way

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve by using one of these

```
let newObj = { all: JSON.stringify(obj.all) };
console.log(newObj);

let newObjJsonString= JSON.stringify({ all: obj.all });
console.log(newObjJsonString);
```

Answer (score 0):

You delete all other object and return your object with its key.

```
   function getWantedObjectWithKey(obj, key){
     var temp = Object.assign({}, obj); 
     Object.keys(temp).forEach(function(value, index){
        if(key != value){
            delete temp[key];
        }
     });
     console.log(JSON.stringify(temp));
     return JSON.stringify(temp);
   }
```

usage:

```
getWantedObjectWithKey(obj, 'all');
```